# Share folder from batch file without asking for admin rights and UAC

Tags: batch, network-shares, uac

I'd like to run a batch file on a remote computer which shares a given folder with everyone. It has to do this

- without asking for admin rights in any way
- without popping up UAC dialog
- without rebooting

So far I have this script, but it keeps giving me the UAC dialog.

```
SET __COMPAT_LAYER=WINXPSP3
if _%1_==_payload_  goto :payload

:getadmin
    echo %~nx0: elevating self
    set vbs=%temp%\getadmin.vbs
    echo Dim WshShell, WshEnv >> "%vbs%"
    echo Set WshShell = CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^) >> "%vbs%"
    echo Set WshEnv = WshShell.Environment^("PROCESS"^) >> "%vbs%"
    echo WshEnv.Item^("__COMPAT_LAYER"^) = "WINXPSP3" >> "%vbs%"
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^)                >> "%vbs%"
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "payload %~sdp0 %*", "", "runas", 1 >> "%vbs%"
    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
goto :eof

:payload
    echo %~nx0: running payload with parameters:
    echo %*
    echo ---------------------------------------------------
    cd /d %2
    shift
    shift
    rem put your code here
    rem e.g.: perl myscript.pl %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
    SET __COMPAT_LAYER=WINXPSP3
    net share MyShare=c:\MyShare /grant:everyone,full
goto :eof
```

Comment: Adam - Consider putting the logic from the VBS `:getadmin` section into an actual VBS script with static values and troubleshoot that to start with. It's likely to be an issue with the VB Script and not really batch so if you could create a VB Script and make the values static to confirm it has the same behavior, then you may get better help by putting the logic in VB on this post and tag it `vbscript`. The batch portions may be irrelevant to the actual problem so that could be distracting people and not needed for troubleshooting your problem. Just a friendly tip that **might** help!!